# Checkbox is not displaying as checked, even though it is

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have PHP script that sets `checked="checked"` to checkboxes based on the database record. However all, but the first occurence of the checked checkbox are displaying checked. Here is what HTML looks like when it browser parses it:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="not_online"><label for="not_online">Not Online</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="facebook" checked="checked"><label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="twitter" checked="checked"><label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
```

And this is what I see in FF26.0

```
[ ] Not Online
[ ] Facebook
[×] Twitter
```

What could cause the issue?

Comment: there is no name for checkboxes. Without name it wont work.

Comment: @Xeos your html working good for me...XP FF26..

Comment: it is also working for me in FF26.
Probably you have some javascript disabling it. inspect the element, probably you will find that the checked attribute has disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name` to each of your checkbox fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="not_online" name="not_online"><label for="not_online">Not Online</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="facebook" name="facebook" checked="checked"><label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="twitter" name="twitter" checked="checked"><label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
```

Comment: For some reason, this solved the issue. Even though name is not a required parameter and the last checkbox works without adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Its is working fine for me what problem are you having?
Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dbDj3/

using your code

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="not_online"><label for="not_online">Not Online</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="facebook" checked="checked"><label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="twitter" checked="checked"><label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
```

It must be some other part of your code that is causing problems